# How to access a Databricks directory with R

Tags: r, databricks

I have a Databricks directory containing R scripts : "/Shared/my_dir"  that I want to access from **R**.

If I do :

```r
setwd("/Shared/my_dir")
```

→ I get an error message : "cannot change working directory".

But if I do for example :
`% run /Shared/my_dir/script1.R`
→ It works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a limitation of the Databricks filesystem implementation. Can you `cd` into the Databricks directory in a normal terminal?

Comment: I have launched a Web Terminal but don't know where to find the Shared folder from the Terminal.

Comment: I think you might have to use `/dbfs/Shared/my_dir` in R

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Thanks for your answer but I have the same error : "cannot change working directory".

Answer (score 1):

When you have code as notebooks, it's not stored on the file system - it's stored inside some database in [Databricks Control Plane](https://docs.databricks.com/getting-started/overview.html), so "normal" file level operations won't work with them.  `%run` is not a file level operation, it was created for work with notebooks.

The only exception is when your code in [Databricks Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/index.html) - in that case, files in a repository are available as `/Workspace/Repos/....` (see [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/work-with-notebooks-other-files.html#programmatically-read-files-from-a-repo)), but it works only with files, not with notebooks.